# View Pager with 3 Items at once

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I am trying to achieve something like in the play store[image: Playstore]

Where all the apps in the view are display 3 apps at a time and the 4th is a preview. while swiping to the left the apps will move and get placed in the respective place making the view cooler.!

Please help me in achieving this view.

```
public class PageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

View itemView;
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public PageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_page, container, false);
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_item);
    Log.i("Position>>>>>>>> ", "" + position);
    textView.setText(arrayList.get(position));
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

    return view == object;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    collection.removeView((View) view);
}

View getLayoutView() {
    if (itemView != null)
        return itemView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_page, null);
    return itemView;
}
```

}

Comment: Most likely, those are not using `ViewPager`, but rather `RecyclerView` or perhaps even `HorizontalScrollView`.

Comment: But adding horizontalScrollView will make the Scroll smoother and I want the item to be in the places in the same place as the previous as they move.

Comment: you `RecyclerView` with `HorizontalLayoutManage` and snaphelper

Comment: Use the `ViewPager` for swtch between views (Ex. HOME,GAMES,MOVIES). Use a `RecyclerViews` to display the items inside a page

Comment: CommonsWare is right - they made it with `RecyclerView` -
 use `<sdk_root>/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer` to see the UI tree

Comment: Thanks guys for the support!

Answer (score 2):

If this is what you are looking for: [RecyclerViewSnap](https://github.com/rubensousa/RecyclerViewSnap/)

[image: Snap to Start Effect]

**Steps to integrate:**

add this line in your `dependencies`:

> implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:1.5'

And then simply have this code:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
SnapHelper snapHelperStart = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START);
snapHelperStart.attachToRecyclerView(startRecyclerView);
```

To learn more about this Snap Effect, check this [Snap to center](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView#snap-to-center-effect) effect

**PS:** It is designed to work with RecyclerView and not ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like a view pager. It is recycle view with Horizontal layout manager. View pager are not build and intended to display such content.If you see the tab bar at the top displaying categories i.e comprises the implementation of (tab layout manager with view pager) or the crouser below tablayout showcase viewpager along with pagertransformation. Hence if you want to achieve it, you can easily achieve it using recycle view instead of using view pager.